# Sent items via Exchange SMTP stored in the users mailbox

Tags: exchange, smtp

Using Exchange 2010 server, is there a way to store outgoing emails in the mailbox's sent items folder when an SMTP authenticated user is sending an email via the exchange server's SMTP server?

(I.e using POP3/SMTP in conjunction with regular exchange, and keeping all sent messages in the users sent items folder stored on the exchange server)

Comment: Good question...that I honestly have never delved into before.  Hmmm...curious now.  If I have time to test I'll let you know what I find.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the nature of how exchange works I don't believe so. Sending mails from outlook (or webapp/EAS) drops the mail in the outbox which creates an RPC call to the hub transport server which then sends it to its destination by using SMTP. If you are sending directly by accessing the HUB transport you are not able to create any RPC calls.

That being said, you could work around it by sending the mail to the authenticated user as well and creating a rule on the mailbox to drop those messages in the sent items.

Alternatively you could look at using the EWS facilities to send emails rather than authenticating against the HUB role directly:

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/01/14/exchange-2007-ews-sending-email.aspx

Comment: I like your thinking outside of the box when mentioning that you can send the e-mail to the user itself and create a rule so that it goes to the sent folder. Here's what I did: I created rules using Exchange Management Shell  with the following command " New-InboxRule -Mailbox <email_address> -Name SentItems -From <email_address> -MoveToFolder '<email_address>:\Sent Items' " and I added the following VBA to the Outlook client: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/automatically-bcc-all-message/

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question last night after I asked a similar question - mine was answered and the solution by BillThor may help you too: [SMTP to MAPI to see email in sent items?](https://serverfault.com/questions/529571/smtp-to-mapi-to-see-email-in-sent-items)