# SMTP to MAPI to see email in sent items?

Tags: smtp, email

I have a property management system that sends email via SMTP. In my case, the SMTP server is my Exchnage server.

The system is poor and known for crashing when sending multiple emails. It also doesn't show what it has sent very well.

My question is: is there a software service that can act as an SMTP server which can convert the send request to MAPI (or similar) to let either Outlook or Exchange send the email as the user so that the email will show in their sent items?

This would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) may meet your needs.  I used it to connect the Thuderbird mail client to an Exchange server when I working on a project.  In addition to providing and SMTP interface, it can also provide IMAP and POP connections.

It can be configured for an individual client, or for enterprise usage.

Comment: EXACTLY what I need :)